# Replacing a rolling average for loop with apply in R

Tags: r, apply

I want to test the correlations between moving averages of varying lengths and a dependent variable.  I've written a for loop that gets the job done but obviously for loops are not the ideal solution.  I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers on how to replace the functionality of this for loop with apply as a more elegant solution?  I've provided code and test data.

```
library(zoo)

# a function that calculates the correlation between moving averages for 
different lengths of window
# the input functions are "independent": the variable over which to apply the 
moving function
# "dependent": the output column, "startLength": the shortest window length, 
"endLength" the longest window length
# "functionType": the function to apply (mean, sd, etc.)

MovingAverageCorrelation <- function(indepedent, depedent, startLength, endLength, functionType) {
# declare an matrix for the different rolling functions and a correlation vector
avgMat <- matrix(nrow = length(depedent), ncol = (endLength-startLength+1)) 
corVector <- rep(NA, ncol(avgMat))
# run the rollapply function over the data and calculate the corresponding correlations
for (i in startLength:endLength) {
   avgMat[, i] <- rollapply(indepedent, width = i, FUN = functionType, 
                         na.rm = T, fill = NA, align = "right")
   corVector[i] <- cor(avgMat[, i], depedent, use = "complete.obs")
  }
return(corVector)
}

# set test data

set.seed(100)
indVector <- runif(1000)
depVector <- runif(1000)

# run the function over the data

cor <- MovingAverageCorrelation(indVector, depVector, 1, 100, "mean")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:100, function(i) cor(rollapplyr(indVector, i, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA), 
        depVector, use = "complete.obs"))
```

If there are no NAs in your inputs this would work and is substantially faster:

```
sapply(1:100, function(i) cor(rollmeanr(indVector, i, fill = NA), depVector, use = "comp"))
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Unfortunately I do have NAs so I have to use the former.